# Play QT movie located in application bundle

Tags: qtkit

I'm trying to run a QT Movie located in my application bundle. Can't get it to work. Can someone advise?

thanks.

paul

```
-(IBAction)runInternalMovie:(id)sender

[


NSString *internalPath;
NSURL *internalURL;
QTMovie *internalMovie;



internalPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"bundledMovie" 
ofType: @"mp4"];
internalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: internalPath];
internalMovie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL: internalURL byReference: YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, there is no `initWithURL:byReference:` method. There are [many ways to create a QTMovie object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002391-DontLinkElementID_70), none of which have a `byReference:` parameter and all of which (except for `+movie`) take an `error:` output parameter.

Once you're loading the movie, you need to hand it to a [QTMovieView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/) for it to display. The easiest way to create such a view is in IB, by dragging it from the Library panel (QuickTime Kit section) to a window in one of your xibs.

Then, either have an outlet in your controller to the movie view and send the movie view a `setMovie:` message after creating the movie, or bind the movie view's “Movie” property to a property of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the `initWithFile:` method of QTMovie:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* moviePath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"bundledMovie" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
QTMovie* movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:moviePath error:&error];
if(movie != nil)
{
    [movieView setMovie:movie]; 
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error loading movie: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to use NSURL, use the following:

```
NSError* error = nil;
QTMovie* movie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bundledMovie" withExtension:@"mp4"] error:&error];
if(movie != nil)
{
    [movieView setMovie:movie]; 
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error loading movie: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```